# How do I make LinearModelFit flexible to number of parameters using FromLetterNumber?

Tags: fitting, hold

I want to run LinearModelFit where the number of parameters is not fixed. For example, the following

```
i = 2;
data = RandomReal[20,{10,3+i}];
lm1 = LinearModelFit[data,FromLetterNumber[Range[2+i]],FromLetterNumber[Range[2+i]];
```

doesn't work, whereas

```
lm1 = LinearModelFit[data,{a,b,c,d},{a,b,c,d}]
```

works as per described, despite `FromLetterNumber[Range[2+i]] == {a,b,c,d}`

Can this be made to work using some kind of `Hold` or do I need to resort to a *design matrix, response vector* format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FromLetterNumber` returns a `String`:

```
Head @ FromLetterNumber @ 3
```

> String

You can wrap the strings returned by `FromLetterNumber` with `Symbol` or `ToExpression` to get `Symbol`s:

```
lm1 = LinearModelFit[data, Symbol /@ FromLetterNumber[Range[2+i]], 
  Symbol /@ FromLetterNumber[Range[2+i]]];
Normal @ lm1
```

> 9.60642 + 0.175108 a - 0.723711 b + 0.850788 c - 0.198777 d

Alternatively,

```
lm2 = LinearModelFit[data, Array[a, 2 + i], Array[a, 2 + i] ] ;
Normal @ lm2
```

> 9.60642 + 0.175108 a[1] - 0.723711 a[2] + 0.850788 a[3] -  0.198777 a[4]

Comment: The `Array` version should be the canonical choice, IMHO. +1